# How can I play SWF files inside my flex app

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex4

Hey the think is, I need to play some swf file inside my flex 4 app, sometimes this swf file can be a Video, or just a object animated, I have a placeholder in my app which I want to play this swf file, how can I do this?

Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [SWFLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html)

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a SWF file? <mx:VideoDisplay> works very well for FLV files.

```
<mx:VideoDisplay id="videoOfDeepLinkingDemo"
    source="http://www.domain.com/folder/FLVFile.flv"
    autoPlay="false"
    width="100%" height="100%" />
```

I have multiple videos appearing on the same page using this method in my [Accessible Flex Tutorial Website](http://www.accessiblerichinternetapplication.com/index.php/Development/How-To-Record-And-Publish-Videos).